# Select row with max value with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains results of some sports competition. Here it is:
[image: table]
And I need to get a table with winner teams. It means, from rows with same MatchIds select entries where Score is maxium for these MatchIds.
Result should look like this:
[image: result table]
I have no idea of correct SQL query.
I'm using MSSQL Server 2018. Thank you.

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2018. What have you tried, and why didn't it work? Also, please don't supply images of data. Data *needs* to be tabular formatted `text`, or DDL and DML statement. Then the volunteers you're asking for help from can consume it.

Comment: What if there is a tie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.score = (select max(t2.score) from t t2 where t2.matchid = t.matchid);
```